# A simple example of rest api in servant or "how to mix monads properly"?

Tags: rest, haskell, monads, servant

I want to build a simple example of a rest api in servant 0.5:

```
data MyData = MyData { var1 :: Int, var2 :: String } 

app :: Application
app = serve api server

api :: Proxy API
api = Proxy

server :: Server API
server = getItems

getItems :: EitherT ServantErr IO [MyData]
getItems = runEitherT $ do
    aa <- nextRandom -- IO
    bb <- getCurrentTime -- IO
    cc <- getDataFromDb -- IO

    --noteT ??? How??? 
    --MaybeT ??? How??? 

    return $ Just [MyData 111 222] 


startApp :: IO ()
startApp = run 8080 app
```

I can't make it compile because of lots errors of "Couldn't match expected type" in different places. I guess it's because I'm mixing 2 different monads in "getItems". But not only.

Comment: This is probably due to [this](http://haskell-servant.github.io/posts/2016-03-19-servant-0.5-release.html#switch-from-eithert-to-exceptt).

Comment: There is not nearly enough code here to reproduce the error (`API` type is missing completely). Nor is there enough information to really tell what `getItems` is supposed to do. But at a glance - `runEitherT` is not needed, you are producing a value of type `EitherT ...`, you don't need to run it. Values of type `IO x` need to wrapped in `liftIO`: `aa <- liftIO nextRandom`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here:

```
getItems :: ExceptT ServantErr IO [MyData]
getItems = runExceptT $ do
```

What [`runExceptT`](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-5.9/transformers-0.4.2.0/Control-Monad-Trans-Except.html) does is going from `ExceptT ServantErr IO [MyData]` to `IO (Either ServantErr [MyData]`. It eliminates the `ExceptT` newtype. But you want to go the other way!

You can use [`liftIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-IO-Class.html) to lift any `IO a` action into a `ExceptT ServantErr IO a` action. It basically tells the `ExceptT` wrapper to "just put the result of the `IO` action in a success context".

Since your whole do-block seems to live in `IO`, you could just write:

```
getItems :: ExceptT ServantErr IO [MyData]
getItems = liftIO $ do
    aa <- nextRandom -- IO
    bb <- getCurrentTime -- IO
    cc <- getDataFromDb -- IO
    ...
```

Instead of lifting each `IO` action separately.

Other common cases:

- If you have a pure `Either`, use [`hoistEither :: Monad m => Either e a -> ExceptT e m a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/errors-2.1.2/docs/Control-Error-Util.html#v:hoistEither) to lift it into `ExceptT`.
- If you have a pure `Maybe`, use [`failWith :: Applicative m => e -> Maybe a -> ExceptT e m a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/errors-2.1.2/docs/Control-Error-Util.html#v:-63--63-) and provide the error.
- If you have a `IO (Maybe a)`, use [`failWithM :: Applicative m => e -> m (Maybe a) -> ExceptT e m a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/errors-2.1.2/docs/Control-Error-Util.html#v:failWithM) and provide the error.
- If you have a `IO (Either e a)`, just wrap it in the `ExceptT` constructor.
- To change the error type carried by an `ExceptT`, use [`withExcept :: (e -> e') -> Except e a -> Except e' a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Except.html#v:withExcept).

All these functions are quite simple and looking at their source code is instructive.

Comment: How can I expose a pure function? Let's say I have it myFunc:: String->String ?

Comment: @elviejo `return` lets you put a pure value in a monadic context. So, if you have a one-argument pure handler, just compose it with `return`.